# Gcc not working

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

How come when i enter

`gcc -framework foundation files -o progname`

into gnu shell it says command not found?

Can someone figure this out i used a guide and did everthing and it still wont work

Comment: Obviously the guide is wrong!

Comment: @Questioner::No updates from you??

Answer (score 1):

Either gcc insn't installed on your computer, or it isn't in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

`gcc --version`

If its not installed then it will not show any version and will say command not found again.

To download it, make sure you are connected to internet, type this in as `root`:

On Fedora / Redhat:

```
yum install gcc
```

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

GCC will get installed resolving the dependencies.